# How to use a dictionary with an external file

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming. 
I have a txt file of short single letter peptide sequences and I am trying to assign the mass of the amino acids to each individual amino acid in each peptide. I then want the sum of the mass of each amino acid for each peptide, plus the addition of 18. I then want this returned as a list of peptide masses.

I have this so far:

```
aaMass = {'G':57.02146, 'V':99.06841, 'Y':163.06333, 'W':186.07931, 'T':101.04768, 'S':87.03203, 'P':97.05276, 'F':147.06841, 'M':131.04049, 'K':128.09496, 'L':113.08406, 'I':113.08406, 'H':137.05891, 'Q':128.05858, 'E':129.04259,'A':71.03711, 'R':156.10111, 'N':114.04293, 'D':115.02694, 'C':103.00919}

file= open('BSA_digest.txt', 'r')

for line in file:

    for AA in line:

        (aaMass)
```

I'm not sure what to do next. I have printed (aaMass) just to see what happens and this just gives me a long list of every single amino acid in my file with its mass.

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Cheers

Comment: You want to initialize a `total` variable to `0` before the loop, then add `18 + aaMass[AA]` each time through the loop, if I understand the question correctly. It might help to see a sample of the input file and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line is a peptide, then each character in the line is the amino acid:

```
with open('BSA_digest.txt') as f:
    masses = [18 + sum(aaMass[c] for c in line.strip()) for line in f]
```

This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and will add up the corresponding masses for each character in the line and add 18, building a list where each entry corresponds to each line in the file.